# "Obtaining file position failed" while using ndarray.tofile() and numpy.fromfile() with FIFOs

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fifo

I am writing some dummy code to learn how FIFOs work in python, (and later use them in my ongoing projects). When I am trying to write, or read from it, I am getting the "OSError: obtaining file position failed" message.

I am trying to transport complex datas between two python codes. I am using FIFOs, because I will need more different channels, to communicate between running modules. I am running them with the bash script, that you can see below.

```py
    #first.py
    import numpy as np
    
    
    data = np.complex64([1, 2, 3])
    
    fifo = open("fifoka", "wb")
    
    data.tofile(fifo)
    
    fifo.flush()
    fifo.close()
```

```py
    #second.py
    import numpy as np
    
    fifo = open("fifoka", "rb")
    data = np.fromfile(fifo, dtype=np.complex64)
    fifo.close()
    
    print(data)
```

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    mkfifo fifoka
    
    python3 first.py | \
    python3 second.py
    
    rm fifoka
```

If I use `fifo.write(data.tobytes())` instead of the `data.tofile(fifo)`, then it is working fine, but according to the [spec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile) it should work the same way.

I have the same problem when I try to read from the same fifo, so I think I am doing the same mistake.

So my question is, how I should use the `np.fromfile()` and the `ndarray.tofile()` correctly in this case.

Comment: Why are you using pipe `|` in your bash? It doesn't seem like `first.py` is outputting anything to `STDOUT`. Simply run `python3 first.py` and `python3 second.py` one after the other and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after I changed the `|` to `&` it is still just hanging.

Comment: Not sure why the two methods are different, but I experienced the same behavior trying to write a numpy array to a fifo. Using `fifo.write(data.tobytes())` worked for me, so +1 for the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a defect in numpy. I just ran into this moving some code from Py2.7, numpy version unknown, to Py3.8.2, numpy 1.17.4.  Changing `arr.tofile(fout)` to `fout.write(arr.tobytes())` made it work.

**Better solution** : if the array you want to write is contiguous, use `fout.write(memoryview(arr))`, which avoids a copy. The utility below will use `memoryview` if possible, otherwise `tobytes`.

```
def arr_tofile(a,outfile):
    if a.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']:
        b = memoryview(a)
    else:
        b = a.tobytes()
    outfile.write(b)
```

I've been using `arr.tofile(f)` via pipe to send data to other processes under 2.x for over a decade, so it's a new defect, and maybe specific to python 3.x ?

It's true that the docs say that `tofile` bypasses the `write` method and uses the fd - but there's no reason to seek or tell in order to perform `tofile`, no reason it should not work on a pipe.

**UPDATE** - it doesn't work in python3 because of a compatibility hack

For python2 operation, the procedure in tofile was to obtain  `FILE*` from the python `file` object; then to flush that file, obtain the underlying file number, and then write to that using the `PyArray_ToFile` function.

Apparently this was broken by Python3, due to internal buffering added in the file object.

So now, it works by calling `npy_PyFile_Dup2` to make a `FILE*` from a python file object, Then, the write is done to the fd from that `FILE*`, using the function `PyArray_ToFile`. Finally, `npy_PyFile_DupClose2(file, fd, orig_pos)` is used to close the new file and seek the original one to the same position. For python2, the `npy_PyFile_Dup2`  and `npy_PyFile_DupClose2` are defined as basically stubs; a single underlying `FILE*` is used as described above.

In Python3 they do a lot more. I didn't go through it all, but `npy_PyFile_Dup2` actually calls `os.dup` using python mechanisms to make a new file handle, and, after the write, `npy_PyFile_DupClose2` does a 'tell' on the new file, followed by a 'seek' on the original python file to skip over the data just written on the other handle.

**Bottom line** - this is a bit of a mess - under python3, it's better to avoid using `arr.tofile(file)`,  even when it works, unless the size of the write is large enough to justify fairly substantial amount of overhead. And it won't work on a non-seekable file at all. Use `file.write(memoryview(arr))` or `file.write(arr.tobytes())` instead, in both cases.

**Obvious Next Question** - can this be fixed to work on pipes?

Maybe - it would rely on being able to detect that the output is a pipe, and in that case to flush the python file object and proceed to write to its file handle (as in the python 2 approach). When writing to a pipe there's no need to support a subsequent 'tell' on the output file.

---

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2f70544179e24b0ebc0263111f36e6450bbccf94/doc/source/release/1.8.1-notes.rst

Deprecations

C-API

The utility function npy_PyFile_Dup and npy_PyFile_DupClose are broken by the internal buffering python 3 applies to its file objects. To fix this two new functions npy_PyFile_Dup2 and npy_PyFile_DupClose2 are declared in npy_3kcompat.h and the old functions are deprecated. Due to the fragile nature of these functions it is recommended to instead use the python API when possible.

---

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/382758355998951cea2b9f6ad1fb83e7dc4c3a02/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c

```
PyObject *file = (from param)
FILE *fd;
npy_off_t orig_pos = 0;  

fd = npy_PyFile_Dup2(file, "wb", &orig_pos);
if (fd == NULL) {
    goto fail;
}
if (PyArray_ToFile(self, fd, sep, format) < 0) {
    goto fail;
}
if (npy_PyFile_DupClose2(file, fd, orig_pos) < 0) {
    goto fail;
}
if (own && npy_PyFile_CloseFile(file) < 0) {
    goto fail;
}
Py_DECREF(file);
Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

---

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/64fb290a8cb8fa9201f18015f3de1186e950a137/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h

```
/*
 * Get a FILE* handle to the file represented by the Python object
 */
static NPY_INLINE FILE*
npy_PyFile_Dup2(PyObject *file, char *mode, npy_off_t *orig_pos)
{
    int fd, fd2, unbuf;
    PyObject *ret, *os, *io, *io_raw;
    npy_off_t pos;
    FILE *handle;

    /* For Python 2 PyFileObject, use PyFile_AsFile */
#if !defined(NPY_PY3K)
    if (PyFile_Check(file)) {
        return PyFile_AsFile(file);
    }
#endif

    /* Flush first to ensure things end up in the file in the correct order */

    [[[... continue to call os.dup via python interface....]]]
}
```

...

```
/*
 * Close the dup-ed file handle, and seek the Python one to the current position
 */
static NPY_INLINE int
npy_PyFile_DupClose2(PyObject *file, FILE* handle, npy_off_t orig_pos)
{
    int fd, unbuf;
    PyObject *ret, *io, *io_raw;
    npy_off_t position;

    /* For Python 2 PyFileObject, do nothing */
#if !defined(NPY_PY3K)
    if (PyFile_Check(file)) {
        return 0;
    }
#endif

    position = npy_ftell(handle);

    /* Close the FILE* handle */
    fclose(handle);

    ....[[more]]...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to how numpy.ndarray.tofile works.

[from the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html)

> When fid is a file object, array contents are directly written to the
>   file, bypassing the file object’s write method. As a result, tofile
>   cannot be used with files objects supporting compression (e.g.,
>   GzipFile) or **file-like objects that do not support fileno() (e.g.,
>   BytesIO)**.

Comment: opening  a 'fifo' object results in a file object that supports `fileno()`, so this does not apply. The question is, why is `tofile()` doing a `tell` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to seek in a FIFO.

On a system-call level, `lseek(2)` is also used to get the file position. So that doesn't work either.

Comment: This appears to be the underlying reason. But why does `tofile()` need to do that?

Comment: @greggo Possibly to ascertain that everything is written? You'd have to delve into the C code of the `tofile` implementation.

Comment: I did... See updated answer. Turns it out it's done to sync the original file with a second output file handle opened to fix a compaiblity issue.